# How to build and run Concorde TSP solver

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-construction, codeblocks, cplex

I'm making a code in C++ that shoudl use a library that is called `Concorde` to solve a well known problem called Traveling Salesman Problem. This library is available [here](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/downloads/downloads.htm)

I've compiled by first running `./configure --with-cplex=<CPLEX_DIR>` and then `make` resulting in two main files `concorde.a` and `concorde.h`. In this way concorde is configure to run and use IBM Cplex as the exact solver.

I'm using Code::Blocks as IDE and in the build options I've added the library (`concorde.a`) under `Link libraries` and included the header in my code.

However when I try to compile my code, it gives me and error indicating that it can't find the implementation of the concorde functions that I call and that are defined in the `concorde.h` file. In this case the error is `"undefined reference to <function>"`.

Can anyone help me with that?

The last part of the build log of codeblocks is the following:

```
    g++ -L/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1251/cplex/lib/x86-64_sles10_4.1/static_pic 
    -L/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1251/concert/lib/x86-64_sles10_4.1/static_pic 
    -L/opt/concorde  -o bin/Debug/SVRPDSP obj/Debug/instance.o obj/Debug/lib/combo.o 
    obj/Debug/lib/IncumbentCallback2C.o obj/Debug/lib/lazyCallback2C.o 
    obj/Debug/lib/lazyCallbackGLS.o obj/Debug/lib/lib_algorithms.o 
    obj/Debug/lib/lib_general.o obj/Debug/solution.o   -lrt  -lilocplex -lcplex 
    -lconcert -lm -lpthread    /opt/concorde/concorde.a
```

ps: I'm compiling on Ubuntu 13.10

Thanks.

Comment: Code::Blocks should spit out what it's using as a link command, what is it trying to do?

Comment: @Collin I've edited above with the last part of the build log. As you can see the concorde lib is being added, so I don't know why it can't find the implementations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Concorde does not support CPLEX 12.5.
I have downloaded [QSopt](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~bico/qsopt/) and launched `./configure --with-qsopt=QSOPT_DIR`.
Finally, the order of the libs is the following:

```
-lilocplex -lconcert -lcplex /opt/concorde/concorde.a /opt/QS/qsopt.a -lm -lpthread
```